# ping problem in wireless router

Tags: ping

n packet tracer my wireless laptop can ping other PC's in the network but PC's cannot ping the laptop.
[image]

```
> R2(config)#do sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 918 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R2
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX1524A08J
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 20.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 2.2.2.2
 log-adjacency-changes
 passive-interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 network 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 20.1.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
======================
R1#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 971 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX152440EW
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 192.168.10.2 255.255.255.252
 clock rate 4000000
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 1.1.1.1
 log-adjacency-changes
 passive-interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 network 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 10.1.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
----------------------
R3#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1080 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R3
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX15249KO1
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 ip address 192.168.20.2 255.255.255.252
 clock rate 4000000
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 3.3.3.3
 log-adjacency-changes
 redistribute static 
 passive-interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 network 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!
ip classless
ip route 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 GigabitEthernet0/1 
ip route 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0 GigabitEthernet0/1 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Comment: Without configurations and output of routing tables, we are unable to help you. Please add them to your question.

Comment: I have posted the configurations

Comment: Please use proper formatting next time, this was unreadable.

Comment: ohh sorry I really didn't mean to do that

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop is able to ping PC's, routing is working. So something on the path (possibly the laptop itself) is filtering it. Check firewalling on each host on the path to determine where ICMP packets are blocked. I don't see anything in your configurations which would block this.

Comment: firewall is disable on the laptop